# Standalone Lightning app URL from ApplicationID (object prefix 02u)

Tags: apex, lightning-apps, app-launcher

We want to build App Launcher in Visualforce page. applicationId for different apps are available in controller with logo url, app name etc.
User has lightning interface enabled, user should be able to open app in lightning interface itself.

Following url displays application tabs vertically, we would like to open view which is actually getting opened only after user clicks one of tabs

https://DomainNameHere.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=aloha#/sObject/ApplicationIdHere/view

Comment: I want know if you solved the question, I need create a similary list. Could you get the url of apps? How structure that paths?

Comment: Not yet, still looking for some possible solution.